# Navigation with Bootstrap doesn't work for mobile

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, razorengine

I am using Bootstrap for navigation. So that it automatically works on a mobile device. If I make the page smaller then at a moment you will see the typical horizontal lines in the right corner. but if you click on it, nothing happens. I mean normally you will see the navigation that you will see on a full width screen. I also have added a picture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Lola Cycling Club</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>



    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                @Html.ActionLink("lola", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })

                <img id="img_logoRight" alt="Logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/lola_heart.png")" />

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <br />
                <div class="float-right">
                    @*<section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>*@

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li @if (@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") == "Account") { @Html.AttributeEncode("class=active")   ; }>
                            @Html.ActionLink("WHO", "Index", "Account")
                        </li>

                        <li @if (@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") == "What") { @Html.AttributeEncode("class=active")    ; }>
                            @Html.ActionLink("WHAT", "Index", "What")
                        </li>

                        <li @if (@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") == "Course") { @Html.AttributeEncode("class=active")      ; }>
                        @Html.ActionLink("AGENDA", "Index", "Calendar")
                        </li>

                        <li @if (@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") == "Instructor") { @Html.AttributeEncode("class=active")       ; }>
                            @Html.ActionLink("PHILOSPY", "Index", "Instructor")
                        </li>

                        <li @if (@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") == "Department") { @Html.AttributeEncode("class=active")        ; }>
                            @Html.ActionLink("BUCKET-LIST", "Index", "Department")
                        </li>





                        <li class="nav"> @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Lola Cycling Club</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: check in console if there are any errors or inspect and check if something is overlapping on it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you also including bootstrap.js and not just bootstrap.css ?